# How to Make Second Row Divs Have Vertical Align Top to Divs on the First Row

Tags: html, css, alignment, positioning, vertical-alignment

My divs on the first row are aligning to the top perfectly. However, some of the divs on the first row vary in height, so the divs on the next row do not align to the very top of the bottom of the divs on the first row (does your brain hurt yet? See my JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RHM5L/258/).

Here is my example code (or see JS Fiddle above):

HTML:

```
<!-- Not Properly Aligned Divs -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="big"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="big"></div>
</div>
<!-- Properly Aligned Below -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="big"></div>
    <div class="small" style='position:relative; top: -30px;'></div>
    <div class="big"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{ 

    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;    

}

.small{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    background: aliceblue;   
    vertical-align:top;
}

.big {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    background: beige;    
}
```

Note: In the second "Container", the divs are doing what I want them to do in the second row. However, to do that, I had to manually manipulate the position of the 3rd div in order to move it up a few pixels. Is there a way to do this without manually inputting the top pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/DhwaniSanghvi/RHM5L/260/

You can use column-count and column-gap property.

HTML:

### HTML:

```
<section id="photos">
  <img src="http://sneakerbardetroit.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/wing-it-air-jordan-2-retro-2.jpg">
  <img src="http://retro-nouveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Retro-Radio-Vector1"/>
  <img src="http://www.topdesignmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Retro-wallpaper-33.jpg"/>
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/retro-microphone-background_23-2147513792.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.freevectors.net/files/large/RetroDesign.jpg"/>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;

   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    2;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         2;
   column-gap:           0px;
}

#photos img {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```